# How do I create a looped script with a wildcard value for the .jpg name, that downloads a set of images using a base url?

Tags: loops, download, wildcard, imacros

I'm trying to download a set of images off of a server (that requires a onetime login to access the set) and I can get view one image at a time. What I want to do via iMacro, or any other method (i'm using firefox, on 64bit win7) is to have a script where I have my base url;

```
http://blah.blah.com/x/00000/content/image/0.jpg?width=2560
```

for instance, and I want to download the 0.jpg image, and then have the script treat the "0" as a wildcard and add a 1, and proceed to download that image. Essentially I want to create a looped script that allows me to download all 540 images in this set having access only to the base url so that all images between and including 0.jpg.....540.jpg are downloaded at width=2560.

Answer (score 1):

all you need is:

```
http://blah.blah.com/x/00000/content/image/{{!loop}}.jpg?width=2560
```

and run your script with play(loop) button stating number of images to save in Max textbox in imacros panel